# using php how to write a code that appends the query data into a file at various positions from the database table

Tags: php

the problem:
using php how do i append the query data which i fetch from the database table into the config file at various specific  positions.

the file which has to be changed

```
$filename = 'C:\wamp\www\disable_user\configurations\config_2';


$fp = fopen( $filename, 'r+');

$sql="SELECT link FROM garden where id ='1' ";
    if ($result= (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) )
        {
```

Fetch one and one row

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                 {

                    $replacement = $row[0];

                    $specific_line = 10; // sample value squeeze it on this line

                    //echo $specific_line;
                    //treat file as an array here.

                    $contents = file('C:\wamp\www\disable_user\configurations\config_2', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );

                    if($specific_line > sizeof($contents))
                     {
                        $specific_line = sizeof($contents) + 1;
                    //////echo $specific_line;
                     }
                    // Remove a portion of the array and replace it with something else

                     //array_splice($input   , int $offset ,$length, $replacement = array())        how to splice an array

                    //array_splice($contents, $specific_line, 0, array($replacement));

                    //array_splice($contents, $specific_line-1, -1, array($contents[$specific_line-1].$replacement));

                    array_splice($contents, $specific_line-1, 1, array($contents[$specific_line-1].",".$replacement.","));//arrays start at zero index
                    $contents = implode("\n", $contents);
                    //echo $contents;
                    //writes a string to a file
                    file_put_contents('C:\wamp\www\disable_user\configurations\config_2', $contents);
                    echo "changes done";
            }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

First you need to grab the query data and then open a file and write the append function. Here is a code hope this helps:

```
<?php
$connect=("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($connect,'database');
$query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (if needed put condition)");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "'.$row['values'].'\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "'.$row['values1'].'\n";
append(array($myfile, $txt));
fclose($myfile);
}
?>
```